# Exporting javascript chart to pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to export Javascript charts generated with `Morris.js` library in rails. Does somebody know any gems or any opinions I can use?
The issue here is that the charts are JS generated and how they can be exported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to download chart as PDF.

http://jsfiddle.net/1roLdqte/48/

```
$('#print').click(function () {
printMe();
});
function printMe() {
  xepOnline.Formatter.Format('line-example',{render:'download', srctype:'svg'});
 }
```

or you can use `gem wicked_pdf` if you want to add more data along with chart.

Comment: +1 for letting the browser do it, _morris.js_ already does an SVG, why not just print it! Simpler solutions are often the best.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible - I've done this with Chart.js charts in the past.

Have a look at [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)

Render a PDF file in the `respond_to` block of your controller. For example:

```
def report
  # do logic stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'report',
             template: 'controller/report.html.erb',
             layout: "report",  # use a different layout than the rest of your site
             page_size: "A4",
             javascript_delay: 2000,
             image_quality: 100,
             background: true,
             disable_smart_shrinking: false,
             title: "Your report"
    end
  end
end
```

You can then hit your report URL (appending `.pdf` to the end) for it to generate your PDF.

Comment: Just a note: current latest versions of both chart.js(2.7.2) and wkhtmltopdf(0.12.4.0) are not playing well with each other. Moreover, both those latest versions have introduced new bugs which prevent charts from being rendered. So you may need to downgrade both libraries: try chart.js 2.6.0 and wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.0. At least it renders something..